# How to get a count even if there are no results corresponding mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am formalating a query to give the number of reports submitted over the last year ordered by date.
I get the current year and month with php:

```
$year = date('Y') - 1;
$month = date('m');
```

and execute the following query:
SQL:

```
SELECT month(date_lm) AS `month` ,
count(*) AS `count`
FROM `reports` 
WHERE (status = 'submitted') 
AND (date_lm > 2012-08) 
GROUP BY month(date_lm) 
ORDER BY month(date_lm) ASC
```

And because there has only been 1 submitted in the last year it gives me only 1 result...

```
| month  |  count  |
|   7    |    1    |
```

But I would like the result set to show:

```
| month  |  count  |
|   9    |    0    |
|   10   |    0    |
|   11   |    0    |
|   12   |    0    |
|   1    |    0    |
|   2    |    0    |
|   3    |    0    |
|   4    |    0    |
|   5    |    0    |
|   6    |    0    |
|   7    |    1    |
|   8    |    0    |
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should LEFT JOIN this table with 1..12 table.
Something like this:

```
SELECT  Months.id AS `month` ,
COUNT(`reports`.date_lm) AS `count`
FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 as ID UNION SELECT 2 as ID UNION  SELECT 3 as ID UNION SELECT 4 as ID 
  UNION  
  SELECT 5 as ID UNION SELECT 6 as ID UNION SELECT 7 as ID UNION SELECT 8 as ID 
  UNION  
  SELECT 9 as ID UNION SELECT 10 as ID UNION SELECT 11 as ID UNION SELECT 12 as ID
) as Months
LEFT JOIN `reports` on Months.id=month(`reports`.date_lm)
                       AND 
                       (status = 'submitted') 
                       AND (date_lm > 2012-08)
GROUP BY Months.id 
ORDER BY Months.id ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/257e8/2)

Comment: Hi thanks, This seems legit but I get a FUNCTION reports.month does not exist.Check with function name parsing and resolution.

Comment: @StevieG: try fixed query

Comment: It's working now, but the output is still not outputting months 9 through to 8. So only when a row that meets the conditions it is added. So there are none with a 0 count.

Comment: thanks appreciate your time man. Is there a way to make months of previous year ie. 09-2012, 10-2012, appear before the others instead of in ascending order?

Comment: I've tried so many ways to do this but I ended up with the error:

ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Answer (score 3):

In order to do this, you could create a 'month' table and then use a left outer join between that table and the reports table.

I've never used mysql so apologies if the syntax is slightly off, but this would be the query:

```
SELECT months.monthNumber,
    count(reports.id) AS `count`
FROM `months` left outer join `reports` on months.monthNumber = month(reports.date_lm) 
WHERE (status = 'submitted') 
AND (date_lm > 2012-08) 
GROUP BY monthNumber
ORDER BY monthNumber ASC
```

Importantly, the count should be of a column in the reports table, not the months table, or else you would never get a zero.

Answer (score 3):

count(col_name) AS `count` will give you count 0

For reference you can visit http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help..

```
SELECT
    t1.month_year AS month,
    COALESCE(SUM(t1.total+t2.total), 0) AS count
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(a.Date, "%Y-%m") AS md,
    DATE_FORMAT(a.Date, "%b-%y") AS month_year,
  '0' AS  total
  FROM (
    SELECT curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY AS Date
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
  ) a
  WHERE a.Date <= NOW() AND a.Date >= Date_add(Now(),INTERVAL - 11 MONTH)
  GROUP BY md
)t1
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%b") AS month, COUNT(*) AS total ,DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") AS md
  FROM reports
  WHERE created_at <= NOW() AND created_at >= Date_add(Now(),INTERVAL - 11 MONTH) AND `status` = 1
  GROUP BY md
)t2 
ON t2.md = t1.md
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_lm, "%b") AS month, COUNT(*) AS total ,DATE_FORMAT(date_lm, "%Y-%m") AS md
  FROM tbl_users 
  WHERE date_lm <= NOW() AND date_lm >= Date_add(Now(),INTERVAL - 11 MONTH) AND status = 'submitted'
  GROUP BY md
)t3 
ON t3.md = t1.md 
GROUP BY t1.md
ORDER BY t1.md
```

this will give data for last 12 months even if there is no data for it with a 0..

Comment: "hope this helps" answers do a poor job of educating the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Please always explain how your snippet works and why it is a good idea.