# MySQL query to return 0 if Count of month returns no results

Tags: mysql

I currently have a MySQL query that returns the count for the amount of orders within a specific month.

```
SELECT YEAR(o.date_added) AS YEAR, MONTH(o.date_added) AS MONTH, Count(*) AS COUNT FROM `order` o WHERE (YEAR(o.date_added) =2012) GROUP BY year, month;
```

There are no records for Months 1 and 2 but I want the Count to return 0 for these months

Comment: In Postgres, You would use "generate_series()" function, which would generate all the months from a range given by You. Unfortunately, in MySQL, there is no such function, but You can implement it as a stored function - see http://www.gab.lc/articles/generate_series_mysql

Comment: I found a solution maybe stupid but it may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397388/how-to-get-a-count-even-if-there-are-no-results-corresponding-mysql