# SQL - Display Count of records even if 0

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to create an SQL query in MS Access that will show how many appointments an employee will have in the current month, even if it is 0. It is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397388/how-to-get-a-count-even-if-there-are-no-results-corresponding-mysql#) question, but i can't get it to work with a WHERE clause.

I have 3 tables:

```
tblEmployees
-employeeID PK
-FirstName ETC

tblEngineersAppts1
-ApptID PK
-EmployeeID*

tblEngineersAppts2
-DiaryID PK
-ApptDate
-ApptID*
```

I want to show all employees, a COUNT of all appointments (DiaryID) in tblEngineersAppts2 even if there are none where ApptDate is the current month.
This is my query, it only shows employees that have an appointment in the current month, it doesn't show those who have none.

```
SELECT tblEmployees.EmployeeID, Count(tblEngineersAppts2.DiaryID) AS CountOfDiaryID
FROM (tblEmployees
LEFT JOIN tblEngineersAppts1 ON tblEmployees.EmployeeID = tblEngineersAppts1.EmployeeID)
LEFT JOIN tblEngineersAppts2 ON tblEngineersAppts1.ApptID = tblEngineersAppts2.ApptID
WHERE (((Format$([ApptDate],'MM/YY'))='03/17'))
GROUP BY tblEmployees.EmployeeID;
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you put the `WHERE` condition you make the `LEFT JOIN` an `INNER JOIN`

```
WHERE (((Format$([ApptDate],'MM/YY'))='03/17'))
```

So Include the `ApptDate` constraint in the `ON` condition.

```
SELECT tblEmployees.EmployeeID, Count(tblEngineersAppts2.DiaryID) AS CountOfDiaryID
FROM (tblEmployees
LEFT JOIN tblEngineersAppts1 ON tblEmployees.EmployeeID = tblEngineersAppts1.EmployeeID)
LEFT JOIN tblEngineersAppts2 
  ON (   tblEngineersAppts1.ApptID = tblEngineersAppts2.ApptID
     AND Format$([ApptDate],'MM/YY')='03/17'
     )
GROUP BY tblEmployees.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Hi, this gives me an error "Join expression not supported". Should have mentioned that im using MS Access.

Comment: Yes, you should. :( ... but looks like only need add parenthesis. Check here http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=242171 and let me know.

Comment: I'm almost there. I can get the results to be displayed as desired, but i keep getting an error in Access when trying to display in design view. This is linked to parenthesis according to Google. The error is "...Cant represent the join expression tblEngineersAppts1.ApptID = tblEngineersAppts2.ApptID AND Format$([ApptDate],'MM/YY') = '03/17' in Design View

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    tblEmployees.EmployeeID,
    (
        SELECT Count(tblEngineersAppts2.DiaryID)
        FROM tblEngineersAppts1
        JOIN tblEngineersAppts2 ON tblEngineersAppts1.ApptID = tblEngineersAppts2.ApptID
        WHERE tblEmployees.EmployeeID = tblEngineersAppts1.EmployeeID
        AND (((Format$([ApptDate],'MM/YY'))='03/17'))
    ) AS CountOfDiaryID
FROM
    tblEmployees
```