# Laravel Query builder, not returning the correct results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

So I have the following query done in Query builder on a GraphQL Query

```
return LearningPath::query()
            ->selectRaw('learning_paths.id,learning_paths.name, count(*) as completed_nodes')
            ->selectRaw('(SELECT count(*) FROM learning_path_levels WHERE learning_path_levels.learning_path_id = learning_paths.id) as total_levels')
            ->selectRaw('(SELECT count(*) FROM learning_path_level_nodes WHERE learning_path_level_nodes.learning_path_level_id = learning_path_levels.id) as total_nodes')
            ->selectRaw('(count(*) * 100) / (SELECT count(*) FROM learning_path_level_nodes WHERE learning_path_level_nodes.learning_path_level_id = learning_path_levels.id) as percentage')
            ->join('learning_path_levels', 'learning_path_levels.learning_path_id', '=', 'learning_paths.id')
            ->join('learning_path_level_nodes', 'learning_path_level_nodes.learning_path_level_id', '=', 'learning_path_levels.id')
            ->leftJoin('learning_path_node_users', 'learning_path_node_users.learning_path_level_node_id', '=', 'learning_path_level_nodes.id')
            ->where('learning_path_node_users.user_id', auth()->id())
            ->orWhereNull('learning_path_node_users.user_id')
            ->groupBy('learning_paths.id','learning_path_levels.id')
            ->get();
```

Which returns the following

```
{
  "data": {
    "learning_path_completed_levels": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Frontend",
        "completed_nodes": 1,
        "total_nodes": 3,
        "percentage": 33
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Devops",
        "completed_nodes": 5,
        "total_nodes": 7,
        "percentage": 71
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Project Manager",
        "completed_nodes": 3,
        "total_nodes": 6,
        "percentage": 50
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But this is not the correct result it should fetch, as it is returning me only the Learning Paths that have at least one level completed ( with the field is_successful marked as true )

It shoud query something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "learning_path_completed_levels": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Frontend",
        "completed_nodes": 1,
        "total_nodes": 3,
        "percentage": 33
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Devops",
        "completed_nodes": 1,
        "total_nodes": 5,
        "percentage": 20
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "QA",
        "completed_nodes": 0,
        "total_nodes": 1,
        "percentage": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "AI",
        "completed_nodes": 0,
        "total_nodes": 5,
        "percentage": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Project Manager",
        "completed_nodes": 3,
        "total_nodes": 6,
        "percentage": 50
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I modify my query so it returns the expected values?

Comment: possible duplicate question?You could try left-joining the table to get count 0. I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397388/how-to-get-a-count-even-if-there-are-no-results-corresponding-mysql

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue